# Absalom's daughter/granddaughter?

Tags: hebrew, nlt

Brown-Driver-Briggs says the word בּת can mean granddaughters but Strong’s says it is never "granddaughters"¹ in KJV.  In I Kings 15:2, I Kings 15: 10 & II Chron. 11:20, it is "daughter" in six translations (four languages) but "granddaughter" in New Living Translation.

**Where (if anywhere) is there evidence to justify the choice of "granddaughter" for this Maakah?**

¹Near as I can tell, KJV does not have "granddaughters" anywhere.

Comment: bible.com aka youversion _audio_ for NLT says "daughter" in I Kings 15:2 but the text they display says "granddaughter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that most versions translate the Hebrew בַּת (bath) as "daughter with the following exceptions: NLT, NKJV.

The word בַּת (bath) most commonly means "daughter" but also means "granddaughters" in a few places such as Gen 46:7, Lev 18:10, etc.

The translation of "granddaughter" may be justified according to Ellicott:

> (1 Kings 15:2) Maachah, the daughter of Abishalom.—The Abishalom of
> this passage, called, in 2Chronicles 11:20, Absalom, is in all
> probability the rebel son of David, whose mother (2Samuel 3:3) was
> also named Maachah. In 2Chronicles 11:21-22, it seems that of all the
> wives (“eighteen wives and threescore concubines”) whom Ŕehoboam,
> following the evil traditions of his father, took, she was the
> favourite, and that even in his lifetime Rehoboam exalted Abijam “to
> be ruler among his brethren.” In 2Chronicles 13:2 she is called
> Michaiah, and said to be the daughter of “Uriel of Gibeah.” This shows
> that, as indeed chronological considerations would suggest, she must
> have been the granddaughter of Absalom. She is mentioned below (1Kings
> 15:13) as prominent in the evil propensity to idolatry.

The Cambridge commentary, Barnes, Gill, Pulpit, and Keil and Delitzsch Biblical Commentaries all take a similar view.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the factors suggested in @Dottard's answer, another problem with calling Maacah the "daughter of Absalom" is that this apparently contradicts 2 Sam. 14, which says:

> 27 And unto Absalom there were born three sons, and one daughter,
> whose name was Tamar: she was a woman of a fair countenance.

In addition, translators may consider it unlikely that the daughter of Judah's most notorious traitor, Absalom, would be allowed to marry into to the royal line of David. A granddaughter would be more plausible. In any case the question of the identity of this Maacah and her relationship to Absalom, Abijah and Asa of full of difficulties, as [this article](https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/maacah-bible) suggests.

These things considered, although "granddaughter" is an unusual translation, it is not an unreasonable one.